# Concurrent File Processing Leads to 'RaceCondition' Error in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, file-io, race-condition

I'm working on a Python project that involves processing multiple files concurrently using the concurrent.futures module. However, I keep encountering a 'RaceCondition' error during execution, and I'm struggling to understand how to resolve it.

```
import concurrent.futures

def process_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file:
        # Process the file content
        pass

file_list = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt']

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    executor.map(process_file, file_list)
```

During execution, I sporadically get the following error:

`RaceCondition: Concurrent modification of shared resource detected.`

I suspect that the error is due to simultaneous file access by multiple threads, but I'm unsure how to synchronize the access properly. I've looked into using locks and semaphores, but I'm not sure if that's the right approach or how to implement it correctly.

Could someone guide me on how to handle concurrent file processing safely in Python? I'm particularly interested in best practices for avoiding 'RaceCondition' errors and ensuring thread-safe file access.

Thank you for your assistance and expertise!

Comment: With the code given, I cannot reproduce this error. Please [edit] the question to contain a [mre].

Comment: There is no `RaceCondition` exception defined in the standard (python.org) Python distribution,, and I've never seen it before. So please give details about the environment you're running under, and, if possible, - as @Kraigolas asked for - a complete program that reproduces your problem.

Comment: Is there possibly a duplicate in the file list, and two different threads handling the same file concurrently?